# Clearing cookies with different paths on Logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5

My domain is suppose **localhost** and I'm storing cookie with "local1" name, The cookie path initially set is  "/" and is present.
after I go to Accounts controller I set a cookie with same name but different path ("/accounts") and I do the same for all the controllers..
so I get around 5 cookies

Now my logout Action is present in Accounts controller and I'm only able to see 2 cookies... one with  "/" path and other with "/accounts" path.. other cookies are not in the context.. how do I delete them all on logout?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the Path property of a cookie, this cookie is no longer posted to all of the pages in your application/server. You can find more info here:[Cookie.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However you can try something like this:

```
string[] yourCookieNamesArray = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

foreach(string cookieName in yourCookieNamesArray)
{
     Response.Cookies[cookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

More info about Request.Cookies.AllKeys [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.allkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: in yourCookieNamesArray different path keys are not there... so solution is invalid